# SQL Network Interface, error:26: Error Locating Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I am encountering this problem, and have read a lot of the links/ blogs/ etc. that offer solutions (opening port 1433, making sure SQLBrowser is running, use the default sqlexpress rather than naming the instance, etc.).  I am waiting for the IT guy to dig into it as I have no rights on that server and in the meantime I notice a few things:

1. Visual Studio connects just fine, and in the SQL browser can fetch data from the tables etc., while my .NET app using Linq To SQL cannot connect (error referenced in title).
2. SSMS on my local machine can connect and update, import, etc. just fine.

Why can some programs (VS, SSMS) connect but the .Net application cannot?  I even created a test UDL file which shows a good connection.  I don't have credentials on the server to actually do anything so I'm just hoping that there is some other item that I can do that will help.

I have used the connection string builder so I know it's not a typo, but right now my connection string is:

```
Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;User ID="";Initial Catalog=PMTools;Data Source=APP1\PMTOOLSET;Initial File Name=""
```

And previously I was using:

```
Data Source=APP1\PMTOOLSET;Initial Catalog=PMTools;Integrated Security=True
```

with the same resulting error 26 - Error Locating Server/ Instance Specified.

I am thinking that the Linq To SQL requires the .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server, and that SSMS and VS do not, and that it is this piece that is hanging up with being able to find a named instance of SQL Server Express. Meaning that there is really nothing I can do without having administrator access to the server the database lives on.

Any chance I'm missing something?  Should I re-do this WPF app so that I use the Entity Framework instead (that is, will the EF have better luck connecting)?  Or is there another framework (say the one VS uses) that I can use to successfully connect to the database?  Or do I just wait for the IT guy to fix everything on the server side?

UPDATE:
I have created a small test application using ADO.NET (Entity Framework) and connect to the server successfully . . . I mapped the same table that was giving me a headache in the LinqToSQL version (through an ObservableCollection) to a datagrid and it populates successfully.  So it appears that the Server is allowing the DbContext class that EF uses (version 6) just fine, but the LinqToSQL dataprovider class requires something else.  With that piece of info is there anything I can do on my end other than convert to the EntityFramework?

Comment: Is your SQL server named __APP1\PMTOOLSET__ ?

Comment: @yW0K5o yes that is the Server Name/ SQL Express name.  This is exactly how SSMS finds it and shows it in the list of data sources available.

Comment: Could you connect to local different SQL Express Server?

Comment: yes, my development machine has a  local copy I used while developing this.  Now I'm trying to deploy so everyone has access to the db.  So I just chose the  new server/ instance from the connection string setting.

Comment: It may be firewall issue. Firewall is not opened for your application. It is only opened to VS and SSMS.